# why doesnt my form value's added to mysql / and how to get 2 decimals at calculation

Tags: php, mysql, forms, insert

1.can someone find why the form doesnt add/submit the values to database ?
i have tried adding values by the form and testing but its not getting in the database

2.and on calculation i get soms values with more than 2 decimals how to fix that because at the script/code i have decimals on 2 maybe someone ?

screenshot of decimals http://prntscr.com/5fbedf

```
<html>
<head>
</head><body>
<?php require "config.php" ; ?>
<?php require "admin_menu.php" ;?>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['verzenden']))
  {
    $id         =   addslashes($_POST['id']);
    $flesnummer      =    addslashes($_POST['flesnummer']);
    $begin_gewicht      =    addslashes($_POST['begin_gewicht']);
    $verbruikt        =    addslashes($_POST['verbruikt']);
    $eind_gewicht      =    addslashes($_POST['eind_gewicht']);
    $verschil        =    addslashes($_POST['verschil']);
    $tara_gewicht        =    addslashes($_POST['tara_gewicht']);
    $over        =    addslashes($_POST['over']);


    mysql_query("INSERT INTO Flesnummer (id, flesnummer, begin_gewicht, verbruikt, eind_gewicht, verschil, tara_gewicht, over) VALUES ('".$id."', '".$flesnummer."', '".$begin_gewicht."', '".$verbruikt."', '".$eind_gewicht."', '".$verschil."', '".$tara_gewicht."', '".$over."')");

    echo '<br><br><br>Fles succesvol toegevoegd';
  }
else
  {
?>
<script>
function totaalIt() {
     var x = document.getElementById("begin_gewicht").value;
     var y = document.getElementById("tara_gewicht").value;
     var z = document.getElementById("verbruikt").value;
     var w = document.getElementById("eind_gewicht").value;
     if ((isNumeric(x, true)) && (isNumeric(y, true)) && (isNumeric(z, true))&& (isNumeric(w, true))) {
         x = parseFloat(x);
         y = parseFloat(y);
         z = parseFloat(z);
         w = parseFloat(w);
         var wverschil = x - y - z + y - w
         var xyzover = x - y - z
         var xyztotaal = x - y - z + y;
         document.getElementById("verschil").value = wverschil;
         document.getElementById("over").value = xyzover;
         document.getElementById("totaal").value = xyztotaal;
         if (confirm ("Formule: Begin gewicht - tara gewicht = vulling - verbruikt = vulling over + tara gewicht = totaal - eind gewicht = verschil(verlies) ?")) {
             document.getElementById("form1").submit();
         }
     } else {
         alert("Numeric Values must be entered.");
     }
}

function isNumeric(sText, decimalAllowed) {
        if (sText.length == 0) return false;
        var validChars = "";
    if (decimalAllowed) {
        validChars = "0123456789.";
    } else {
        validChars = "0123456789";
    }
        var isNumber = true;
        var charA;
    var decimalCount = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < sText.length && isNumber == true && decimalCount < 2; i++) {
            charA = sText.charAt(i); 
        if (charA == ".") { 
        decimalCount += 1;
        }
            if (validChars.indexOf(charA) == -1) {
               isNumber = false;
            }
        }
        return isNumber;
}
</script>

<form name="form1" id="form1" action=" <?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?> " method="POST">
<table>
<input type="hidden" name="id" >
<tr><td>Flesnummer:</td><td><input name="flesnummer" id="flesnummer" type="text" size"4">
  <tr><td>Begin gewicht:</td><td><input name="begin_gewicht" type="text" id="begin_gewicht" size="4" />
    Kg</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Tara gewicht:</td><td><input name="tara_gewicht" type="text" id="tara_gewicht" size="4" />
    Kg</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Verbruik:</td><td><input name="verbruikt" type="text" id="verbruikt" size="4" />
    Kg</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Vulling over:</td><td><input name="over" type="text" id="over" size="4" readonly="true" />
    Kg (automatisch berekend)</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Eind gewicht:</td><td><input name="eind_gewicht" type="text" id="eind_gewicht" size="4" />
    Kg</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Eind gewicht: <img title="Eindgewicht volgens berekening" src="img/question.gif" width="15" height="15" onMouseDown="Eindgewicht volgens berekening" alt="Eindgewicht volgens berekening." /></td><td><input name="totaal" type="text" id="totaal" size="4"  readonly="true" />
    Kg (automatisch berekend)</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Verschil(verlies):</td><td><input name="verschil" type="text" id="verschil" size="4"  readonly="true" />
    Kg (automatisch berekend)</td></tr>
  <tr><td><input type="button" name="verzenden" id="verzenden" value="Verzenden" onClick="totaalIt()" /></td></tr>
   </table></form>

<?
  }
?>
```

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php tag error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Your else isn't catching anything. By the way, I recommend naming variables in an international language (e.g. English), imagine if you had to take over someone's code and he wrote it in Swedish.

Comment: if i add `<?php tag error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` i got blanco page ?

Comment: You have a syntax error then. Before `<html>` write `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); ?>` no `tag` in there

Comment: i have done that but nothing happend screenshot http://prntscr.com/5fbqcj

Comment: Try `echo mysql_error(). "\n";` after your query. See if mysql is having a problem.

Comment: for rounding the numbers to two decimal points you can use round($variable, 2); 

Be wary though when using rounded numbers for further calculations. Best use seperate variables that are rounded for display until you did all your calculations.

Comment: ` echo mysql_error(). "\n"; ` like this ? http://prntscr.com/5fbtld

Comment: Yes like that. Does that produce an error from MySQL on that query? Like  error on line whatever...?

Comment: no not that i can see there are no messages on the screen or error codes

Comment: Ok, so when you fill out the form and submit it, there are no errors produced by the page or by the `mysql_error`?

Comment: no errors on display page no errors on filled page no error on submiting form no error after reloading page from submit

Comment: So on submission, it just says: "Fles succesvol toegevoegd"?

Comment: no it don't say "bottle succesfull added" (in english) i just got the form again after submit(verzenden)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your form, try turning your `button` input to `submit`:

```
<input type="button" name="verzenden" id="verzenden" value="Verzenden" onClick="totaalIt()" />
```

TO:

```
<input type="submit" name="verzenden" id="verzenden" value="Verzenden" onClick="totaalIt()" />
```

Your button is not registering the `name` so it's not getting to the `$_POST['verzenden']` in your check:

```
// There is no $_POST['verzenden'] with the button.
if(isset($_POST['verzenden'])) {
```

Comment: OMG thank you im so stupid i think i have to take a break pff thanks for this guys :)

Comment: do you maybe no how to fix the 2 decimals of the form ?

Comment: You can use `number_format($number,2);` this will force 2 decimal points

Comment: `function isNumeric(sText, decimalAllowed) {
        if (sText.length == 0) return false;
     var validChars = "";
 if (decimalAllowed) {
     validChars = "0123456789.";
 } else {
     validChars = "0123456789";
 }
        var isNumber = true;
        var charA;
 var decimalCount = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < sText.length && isNumber == true && decimalCount < 2; i++) {
            charA = sText.charAt(i); 
     if (charA == ".") { 
  decimalCount += 1;
     }
            if (validChars.indexOf(charA) == -1) {
               isNumber = false;
            }
        }
        return isNumber;
}`

Comment: Oh, wait, is that a javascript calculation or a PHP displayed calculation?

Comment: this i what i have at my <script> section so that has to do it but thats not working :(

Comment: javascript that calculate the fields

Comment: According to another StackOverflow, you round using this formula:  `Math.round(num * 100) / 100` After that you can probably just pad the decimal points with a `0` if there are less than 2 decimals.

Comment: thanks i found it `document.getElementById("verschil").value = wverschil.toFixed(2);
         document.getElementById("over").value = xyzover.toFixed(2);
   document.getElementById("totaal").value = xyztotaal.toFixed(2);`